# How to get started with gfortran on a Mac?

Tags: macos, fortran

Just finished installing the compiler gfortran 6.1. El Capitan. Next, I want to know how to run a file. So, I have a few questions:

1. Which extension should I use to save the file? Is it .f90 or something else?
2. What kind of software can be used to edit and save the source code?
3. Once I save the file, how do I compile it? Is is gfortran followed by the file name (with path) in the Terminal? Also, how does the path look like on a Mac?

A step by step guide would be a great help. I am a first time Mac user. :)

Comment: As noted in the answer by @haraldkl you can use any text editor to create the file, however if you're after something a bit more focused on code developement and fortran you may want to post a separate question at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ to get software recommendations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. .f90 for free formatted sources is commonly used
2. Any texteditor you are comfortable with and used to, vim for example
3. `gfortran /your/source/file` that would be with an absolute path. If you are in the directory of the source file already you do not need to specify the complete path.

Step by step "hello world":

- Create a text file with your Fortran program
- Just to give a command line example without the need for an editor (this is not what you typically would do):

  - Open the terminal, then enter

    ```
    cat >hello.f90 <<EOF
    program hello
      implicit none
      write(*,*) 'hello world'
    end program hello
    EOF
    ```
- Compile your program in the terminal with: `gfortran hello.f90`
- Execute it in the terminal with `./a.out`
- If you want another name use the `-o` option:

  ```
  gfortran -o hello hello.f90
  ./hello
  ```

Comment: I have heard some people like TextWrangler to edit Fortran source files: http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/twprogrammer.html

Comment: Thanks. I managed to compile a file and apparently I have no errors. But now, how can I make the program display the stuff (e.g. in this case, display 'hello world')?

Comment: This is what the `./a.out` or `./hello` commands in the answer do. These commands should be executed in the terminal from the same directory in which you compiled the source file(s) (i.e. where the generated executable exists).

Comment: Works well, thanks! So I have to do this in the terminal every time I want to compile and execute it, right? Is there any "shortcut" to this?

Comment: Also - this will work in the same way for visual stuff (e.g. plots)?

Comment: Not quite sure, what you mean by shortcut. Fortran is a compiled language, you always need to compile your source code to create an executable. Usually, the compiling is more involved than just compiling a single file, for this build systems exist (Makefiles for example), and there are IDEs available, which allow you to compile your code  from within a GUI editor. I am not familiar with those, however. My development environment is shell+vim and for compilation I use waf.