# Fortran doesn't find input file in directory

Tags: macos, fortran

I wrote a program in fortran (f90, using gfortran) that receives its input from a .txt file (list o integer numbers).

```
  PROGRAM prog_example

    implicit none

    INTEGER i,j
    CHARACTER file1*20
    CHARACTER*8, DIMENSION(10,3000) :: data
    
    302 FORMAT (a20)

    WRITE(*,*)'Type the name of the input file:'  
    CALL SYSTEM("pwd") !show the directory    
    READ(*,302) file1
    OPEN(20,file=file1,status='old')     

END
```

When I run the code and type the name of the file (in.txt), that is in the folder, it returns an error stating it could not find the file. This code runs just fine on my old Windows computer, but on my Mac, it does not. What could be the problem?

all files are in Usr/documents/prog_example that contains:

```
Sypome5.cbp Sypome5.depend  Sypome5.exe Sypome5.layout  
a.out       bin     in.txt      main        main.f95    obj
```

I get the following error message:

```
 At line 101 of file main.f95 (unit = 20) Fortran runtime error: Cannot open file 'in.txt': No such file or directory
 
 Error termination. Backtrace:
 #0  0x104620b17
 #1  0x10462178f
 #2  0x104622113
 #3  0x1046e6f23
 #4  0x1046e7157
 #5  0x10456155b
 #6  0x104562337
 #7  0x10456314b
```

After I added the command to print the directory I learned it is running in my root directory (Users/pedro), but it should be running in Users/pedro/documents/prog_example. If I paste the input file in the root directory it works just fine, but it is quite messy to have those files there.

Comment: Please show us a *complete* code illustrating the problem, and also please include the input you provide and an ls of the directory in question - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Edit the question to include this info.

Comment: I added some more info, the code is quite long and the issue seems to be not in the code, but maybe on the OS or compiler. As I said, it runs without problems on Windows.

Comment: maybe trim the file name when opening the file as it may be (automatically padded with spaces. Also publish the exact (with copy and past, not retype, of the error message.

Comment: You don't have to show a long code. Just a very short *complete* code that reads in a file name and tries to open that file, and gives the same error as you are seeing now. We want to try and reproduce what is going wrong for you on our own machines and debug it there, but currently you are not providing us with enough information to let us do that. ls -l on the directory could be useful as well.

Comment: The usual problem is that the path to the file went wrong somehow: if you can make it show you what it thinks the complete path and filename is, there is a good chance that you can fix it.

Comment: Hi Ian, I edited with a simpler code that gives exactly the same error. Many thanks!

Comment: Eating dinner but that looks like it should work. In the directory which contains both the executable a.out and the input file in.txt can you issue the following command, please: pwd; ls -l; ./a.out and tell us the output.

Comment: Try adding a line `CALL SYSTEM("pwd")` to print the name of the working directory where it is actually looking for the file.

Comment: Better is the standard `Call execute_command_line( 'pwd' )` rather than the non-standard `system`. I know it's only debugging, but best to chose the right way when there is one to those who don't know!

Comment: Hi @IanBush, I checked and it is running in a different directory (Users/pedro). How could I make it run in the main directory, i.e., at the location of the executable (Users/pedro/documents/prog_example/)?

Comment: Please edit the question to show exactly how you are running the code

Comment: What I really want to know is which directory you are in when you type the command to run the program, and *exactly* what command you use to start the program

Comment: @IanBush, I am at Users/pedro/documents/prog_example/. First I compile the code with `gfortran main.f95`, then I run `open main`.

Comment: OK, I had assumed macos was more Unix like, or I am misunderstanding.  Are you typing "open main" at a command line? Or is it in some IDE/editor?

Comment: How exactly are you doing `open main`? Are you clicking somewhere or typing this somewhere? Where exactly?

Comment: @IanBush, I'm typing in the command line.

Comment: I'm sorry, but if you are typing open main at the command line you'll need a macos specialist, as that's nothing I recognise at all. What happens if you cd Users/pedro/documents/prog_example and the type ./a.out after you compile it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37665708/how-to-get-started-with-fortran-on-a-mac might be of use